# Как разобрать MIME с неуникальными вложенными границами частей?

Tags: email, mime

RFC я читал, знаю, что все Boundaries должны быть уникальны. И все таки, как вы считаете, что лучше делать на практике:

1. проверять каждого кандидата и откатываться, закрывая все части текущей иерархии;
2. или завершать рекурсивный разбор, т.е. игнорировать неуникальность внешних границ?

Answer (score 1):

В принципе, если в письме количество начальных записей соответствует конечным, то можно закрыть глаза на некоторое несоответствие стандарту. Естественно, в этом случае никто не может гарантировать правильность конечного результата.

Comment: Спасибо, вообще-то имелось в виду примерно следующее:
    ...
    --bnd1
    ...
    --bnd2
    ... (1)
    --bnd1--
    ...
    --bnd2--
    --bnd1--

т.е. в точке (1) обнаруживаем, что внешняя часть закрывается.
С другой стороны --bnd1-- в этом месте можно считать просто текстом.
Интересует мнение - что лучше ?

Comment: К сожалению, не удается форматировать текст в комментарии, отступ в
4 пробела в начале строки не работает.

Comment: Нда, тяжелая ситуация. Если парсить сообщение в один проход, то проще не замечать преждевременное закрытие внешнего блока и сверять закрывающие границы только с соотвествующими открывающими из вершины стека.

Comment: На практике я думаю лучше документировать подобные ошибки и смотреть, насколько часто они встречаются. Если редко, то не стоит об этом даже думать.

Comment: Ну, оба варианта не особенно тяжелы (просто просматриваем стек назад). MS Outlook следует варианту 1. Наверное это ближе к RFC. 
Там нигде явно не указано, как поступать при таких ошибках в формате. Просто хотелось узнать, какой из подходов выглядит более логичным.